# Looking for a recent reference for a result of Shelah

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

In 1984 Shelah showed the consistency of $\aleph_1=\mathfrak b<\mathfrak s=\mathfrak a=\aleph_2$, however the original paper is hard to read, because of the old typesetting.

Is there a more modern exposition of this result in some paper or textbook?

Comment: Did you look at the Handbook's chapter by Blass? Halbeisen's book might also have something about this.

Comment: As far as I can tell Blass only mentions that Shelah proved the consistency of $\mathfrak b<\mathfrak a$ on page 52, referencing the same article I mentioned in the question. I don't know Halbeisen's book, I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling a proof of the consistency of $\mathfrak b<\mathfrak s$, which seems to be following Shelah's construction, can be found as theorem 4.5 in Uri Abraham's chapter of the handbook.